# Mute Audio for a certain interval of a track

Tags: c#, audio

Am developing the application in .net. In that application we want to select the song and in that song we should "**mute /  hide**" some interval of time.

For eg:
If we have the length of the audio file is 1:00 min, we have to hide the Interval of audio from "***0:36 to 0:50***" sec from that 1 min audio.

Comment: What framework or audio methods do you use for audio playback?

Comment: You use 4 lines for your question and 3 lines for thanks/signature etc. Please read the http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures for guidlines on how to us (or not to) signatures. Update: Thanks Bobby for removing!

Answer (score 0):

Use [Splicer](http://splicer.codeplex.com/): A free open source library for the .Net framework that aims to simplify developing applications for editing and encoding audio and video using DirectShow.

Comment: Hi Jalal, can i have sample source for editing the audio file /  cut the audio file

Answer (score 0):

If you have your sound file in mp3 format, you'll have to DECODE it, edit it programaticaly, and re-encode it later.

If by 'hide' you mean cut out, it is very simple in PCM world.  You'll just copy the samples that you need to the output buffer, omitting ones that you don't need.

If you plan to edit audio from code, you'll have to learn what is sample, how the audio is represented in the memory, and so on, anyway.